# Eliminating incomplete genes from a fasta file in unix

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file with something like the following (amino acid sequences shortened for simplicity):

```
>nitrite_reductase
MYWGGPPAAWYGG

>ammonium_transporter
MWYY
```

I would like to keep all text between the first and second > signs and remove the second > and everything after it. I tried looking through the cut, awk, and sed documentation but couldn't find any immediately obvious ways of doing that. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, you can use

```
sed '1 n;/>/ Q' input.fasta
```

- `1 n;` print the first line and go to the next
- `/>/ Q` when the line matches `>`, end.

In other sed implementations, you can use

```
sed '1 n;/>/,$ d' input.fasta
```

Again, the first line is processed. From a later line matching `>` to the end the lines aren't printed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe '$cnt++ if /^>/; last if $cnt > 1;' input.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`$cnt++ if /^>/;` : Initially, `$cnt` is `undef`, which in this context evaluates to 0. `$cnt` is incremented by 1 when a fasta header is encountered. So after the first header it sees, it becomes 1.

`last if $cnt > 1;` : Exit the loop (and the script) when `$cnt` is greater than 1, that is, at the second fasta header. Thus, the second sequence in the file, and the rest of them, is never printed. Even for large files, the exit happens quickly - right after the first sequence.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)